# What is the difference between `$state.current.name` and `$state.$current.name`?

Tags: user-interface, angular-ui-router

Is there any difference, or are both the same?

`$state.current.name`:

```
$state = {{$state.current.name}}
$stateParams = {{$stateParams}}
$state full url = {{ $state.current.url.source }}
```

`$state.$current.name`:

```
$state = {{$state.$current.name}}
$stateParams = {{$stateParams}}
$state full url = {{ $state.$current.url.source }}
```

I receive the same output in both.

Answer (score 2):

`$state.current` is a variable of the ui-router API (to get used by the developer) whereas `$state.$current` is a "private" object reflecting the execution context of the UI-router in real time.

`$state.$current` contains the data in `$state.current` but also a lot more (like the chain of states `$state.$current.path`).